# SimpleFormController Issue in Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I need to know about as shown below error :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create command without commandClass being set - either set commandClass or (in a form controller) override formBackingObject
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.BaseCommandController.createCommand(BaseCommandController.java:361)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.formBackingObject(AbstractFormController.java:481)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.getErrorsForNewForm(AbstractFormController.java:361)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.showNewForm(AbstractFormController.java:341)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.handleRequestInternal(AbstractFormController.java:281)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:746)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:716)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:65)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

What i am doing is default page is index.jsp in this page forward to another page.Here getting error.Please find the below code :

MainController.java

```
package com.ht.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;

public class MainController extends SimpleFormController  {


    @Override
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
            throws Exception {

        System.out.println("**************  onSubmit ************************");

         String msg=null;

             msg="Registration success";

        return  new ModelAndView("result","resMsg",msg);
    }


}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

 <bean id="sic"  class="com.ht.controller.MainController"/>


 <bean id="suhm"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
     <property name="mappings">
        <props>
           <prop key="main.htm">sic</prop>

        </props>
     </property>
   </bean> 

    <bean id="vr"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
       <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
       <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

index.jsp

```
<jsp:forward page="main.htm"/>
```

main.jsp

```
<form:form method="post">
  Student no:<form:input path="sno"/><br>
  Student name :<form:input path="sname"/><br>
  Student address :<form:input path="sadd"/><br>
  <input type="submit" value="register"/>
</form:form>
```

I didn't get any idea about this.So please suggest me what to do for this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject those class while create bean instance

`<bean id="sic"  class="com.ht.controller.MainController">
<property name="commandClass" value="You class Package"/>
<property name="commandName" value="name of command"/>
</bean>`

Comment: Can you explain once @Model FormDto formDto?,I am trying place this asking model class.@Vijay

Comment: FormDto will be ur DTO class which you have to create that can hold ur form data. As your form looks it should have three data members sname, sno and sadd

Comment: I got compile time error placed same as above The method onSubmit(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, StudentCmd, BindException) of type MainController must override or implement a supertype method.@vijay

Comment: on get request where ur form in rendered add new object of StudentCmd.
model.add("studentCmd", new StudentCmd());
where "studentCmd" --> should match to commandName defined in form tag.

Comment: I didn't get you So please do in above example.@vijay

Comment: updated answer, your controller method will be same as you have posted in ques